# How to properly print the content of a list in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a small console application to test some stuff with collections.

My code looks like this:

```
namespace Collections
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      List<string> cars = new List<string>();

      cars.Add("BMW"); //0
      cars.Add("Tesla"); //1
      //Add Honda here
      cars.Add("Audi"); //2
      cars.Add("Ford"); //3

      cars.Insert(2, "Honda");

      foreach(string car in cars)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(cars);
      }

      //Console.Read();
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the output to be

> BMW
>   Tesla
>   Honda
>   Audi
>   Ford

But my output actually looks like this

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

But I can't find my mistake here.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mcve], **in text form**, in the question.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(car);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're printing `cars` - the collection - instead of `car` - the current iteration.
Change it to `Console.WriteLine(car);`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!!